# Retrieve List of String from webservice in android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-ksoap2

I am trying to retrieve List of String from my SoapObject.I am using KSoap2 to call my webservice which returns List of Strings.Here is my code

```
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

Can anybody help me to get all the list elements from my SoapPrimitive object.

like `List abc =response.getList() or something`??

Answer (score 1):

Your case is a simplified version of  this case: [Parsing kSoap response to array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405592/parsing-ksoap-response-to-array-of-objects)

But with a minor difference, your objects are simple:

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
SoapObject soapresults = (SoapObject)result.getProperty(0);

int count = soapresults.getPropertyCount();

ArrayList<PT> simplifiedList = new ArrayList<PT>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
     soapresults.getPropertyAs(PT)(i)
}
```

Comment: This is what i have done..SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
         SoapObject soapResult = (SoapObject)result.getProperty(0);
         int count = result.getPropertyCount();
         prjList = new ArrayList<String>();
         for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
         {
          prjList.add(soapResult.getPropertyAsString(i));
         }

Comment: Thanks for your response @Thunder-KC Inc...I tried your code but getting the following exception when I am setting my Spinner(Dropdown) with the value of above list element with this code..
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("projectListSpinner", simlifiedList);

Exceptions
12-04 11:14:01.819: E/AndroidRuntime(552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 11:14:01.819: E/AndroidRuntime(552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nevaeh.emsandroid/com.nevaeh.emsandroid.TourRequest}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 11:14:01.819: E/AndroidRuntime(552): 
plz Help me Sir

Comment: is this list the list extracted from ksoap?

Comment: sir this list extracted from KSoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8

Comment: what I want to know is where exception occurred after filling list when you want to put it to intent or another time?

Comment: What is the relation of this exception to your question and my answer?

Comment: The excetion occurred  after filling list when I want to put it to intent because it is setting a null value.

Comment: Can you debug the program and answer me the following question:

which value is null? the intent, simlifiedList, or the elements in the list

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer with help of @Thunder 's suggestion
Instead of
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
We have to use

```
java.util.Vector<String> result11 = (java.util.Vector<String>)envelope.getResponse(); // to get List of Strings from the SoapObject.. then
ArrayList<String> prjList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String cs : result11)
{
prjList.add(cs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the strings of your soapObject like this:

```
SoapObject resSoap =(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn; 
int count = resSoap.getPropertyCount();
for (int i=0; i<count;i++){
    SoapObject so = (SoapObject) resSoap.getProperty(i);
    int idxic = so.getPropertyCount();
    lst= new String[idxic];
    String item;
    for (int e=0; e<idxic;e++){
        item=so.getProperty(e).toString();
        lst[e]=item;
    }
}
```